# Visual Studio 2012 Debugger suddenly stops while debugging Azure project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, azure, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

When I'm debugging my Azure project (1 Web + 1 Worker Role instance) locally, the debugger often just stops and the role instances are restarting.

I have no clue why this is happening, there are no uncaught exceptions and if I run the project without setting breakpoint everything works just fine. 
However when I set breakpoints and move through the code using Step Over / Step into, the debugger just stops at random intervals.

Does anyone know what is causing this / where I can find additional logs that may shed some light on this?

**Update:**

Either I overlooked this previously or it didn't get logged to the Output window, but I now got the following error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007fde4a4167f in WaWorkerHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfffffffffffffff8.
The Common Language Runtime cannot stop at this exception. Common causes include: incorrect COM interop marshalling, and memory corruption. To investigate further, using native-only debugging.
```

I'm pretty sure that's not my application's fault – as I mentioned, the exact code I'm debugging runs fine when I don't set breakpoints and step through manually.

Any ideas?

**Update 2**:

Frome the Bootstrapper (old) log:

```
[00012264:00001260, 2013/03/26, 11:37:19.777, 00100000] <- CRuntimeClient::OnRoleStatusCallback(0x0000006BD7718C00) =0x800706be
[00012264:00008432, 2013/03/26, 11:37:19.804, 00100000] <- CRuntimeAgent::RemoveEndpointRegistration(0x0000006BD76F60E0) =0x80070005
[00012264:00001260, 2013/03/26, 11:37:19.811, 00040000] Client process WaWorkerHost.exe is the role host.
[00012264:00008432, 2013/03/26, 11:37:19.830, 00100000] <- CRuntimeAgent::UnregisterEndpoint(0x0000006BD76F60E0) =0x80070005
[00012264:00001260, 2013/03/26, 11:37:19.830, 00080000] Failed to contact the role host process. Treat role as unhealthy.
```

The file ends with that – in the next bootstrapper log, the startup of role instances is being logged. 
Can it be that debugging prevents the bootstrapper from contacting roles and thus deciding they are unhealthy and must be restarted?

**Last Update:**

I wiped my project and did a fresh checkout from the repository. As it turns out, there was a missing reference in one of my class libraries. The missing reference never showed up as compile error, supposedly because there was an older version laying around somewhere.

To all others that find themselves in a similar situation, I can only recommend trying to do the same: completely cleaning their code base and see if the issue disappears. In all the logs I searched I never encountered a "MissingReferenceException" – would have saved me a lot of time today

Comment: What are you using as a development server?

Comment: I was using IIS Express, I tried switching to IIS Web Server  because I've read somewhere that that may be the cause, but the issue remained. I'm not sure though if I need to add more configuration – I only changed the radio button in the Cloud project settings to "Use IIS Web Server" and installed IIS via programs / features.

Comment: Just to be sure. Try uninstalling the Azure SDK & Tools then perform clean install http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/

Comment: Just noticed an exception I seem to have overlooked previously, updated question

Comment: Do you have IntelliTrace enabled? If so disable it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2012/05/07/windows-azure-worker-role-crashing.aspx

Comment: I already tried that, too. Following my exception from above I found an event log contining `Faulting application name: WaHostBootstrapper.exe`. I'm now trying to find bootstrapper logs – do you by chance know where I can find those, @plurby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enable Diagnostics in Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/)

**UPDATE 1**

You could try enabling the logs

Go to **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\DevelopmentStorage** directory. You'll see two files
[image]

Open file **DevelopmentStorage.201210.config** and change **LoggingEnabled** to true.

[image]

References:

[Windows Azure worker role crashing](http://blinditandnetworkadmin.blogspot.com/2012/05/windows-azure-worker-role-crashing.html)
[WaWorkerHost.exe crashes role](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/543da280-2e5c-4e1a-b416-9999c7a9b841)

**UPDATE 2**

**WaHostBootstrapper** log is located in **C:\Resources\Directory\DeploymentID.Role.DiagnosticStore\WaHostBootstrapper.log**

Other logs:

**WaWebHost**
*C:\Resources\Temp\Guid.Role\RoleTemp\WaWebHost.log*

**WaIISHost**
*C:\Resources\Temp\DeploymentID.Role\RoleTemp\WaIISHost.log*

**IISConfigurator**
*C:\Resources\Temp\DeploymentID.Role\RoleTemp\IISConfigurator.log*

**IIS Logs**
*C:\Resources\Directory\Guid.Role.DiagnosticStore\LogFiles\W3SVC1*

**Windows Event Logs**
*D:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs*

**UPDATE 3**

Defining local storage in Azure Application creates a new folder so path to your Azure Compute Emulator is %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\dftmp\

Comment: Thanks for your help plurby, the development storage log option helped me greatly. I just want to point out here that the log locations from your second update refer to Azure VMs, not the local file system (logs are in `AppData\Local\dftmp`, at least on my machine)